# Apache Tomcat 7 Websocket port

Tags: tomcat, websocket

Is it possible to set the Websocket protocol to listen to a different port for Tomcat 7?
Nothing is evident from here: `https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the section [1.7. Relationship to TCP and HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.7)  of the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) about the WebSocket protocol:

> The WebSocket Protocol is an independent TCP-based protocol. Its only
> relationship to HTTP is that its handshake is interpreted by HTTP
> servers as an Upgrade request.
>
> By default, the WebSocket Protocol uses port 80 for regular WebSocket
> connections and port 443 for WebSocket connections tunneled over
> Transport Layer Security (TLS).

To change the HTTP/WebSocket port in Apache Tomcat, open Apache Tomcat's `server.xml` file and search for an entry similar to this one:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Replace `8080` with the desired port number, save the file and restart Apache Tomcat.